# How to access my secondary layout items through my activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two XML layouts for a single activity. In the main layout file I've defined a list view and how this list view items look like is defined by the second layout.

Here is the main layout which has the list view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_1"
        android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the second layout file that defines how the list items should look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the MainActivity I've set the main layout as the content view. Now I want to access the second layout items like text view and image view, but using LayoutInflater is not an option; Because I've tried that and it does not work or I don't know how to write the correct syntax. How can I access these items through their ids or something? Thanks.

Comment: did you use Adapter? If yes, post your adapter code.

Comment: Are you trying to add the realtive layout as a custom layout to the listview?

Comment: @Bri6ko yeah. That's true.

Comment: @nr4bt There is no need to see the adapter. because I easily get access to them. I want to define text color for my text-views in the second layout.

Comment: refer to the tutorial that I've posted, it's pretty much the same as the one @klifa posted

Comment: @AliAllahyar But the point is how do you access them? through adapter or not? That's why I asked, because if you need to change the list item for listview, you'll need customadapter, which it's already in the one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize the text view and image view depending on the content you should implement a custom adapter

[HERE IS HOW](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

Follow the simple tutorial and im sure your problem will be solved.

If not, give more information when and why you want to access it

**EDIT:**

It depends where you want to access it. If you are for example in the item click method, you could access the view like this

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,                     long id) {

    if (viewItemAnterior != null)
    {
    Button boton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.list_boton);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it and now I can access them through the inner getView method.

Comment: ok great. I have edited the answer based on some comments from you. Dont forget to mark an answer as correct if it solved your problem! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this tutorial, I think it has the things you are looging for. [Android Custom Adapter for ListView](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)

Comment: Thanks sir, I realized my mistake. But Isn't there a way other than using the adapter inner getView method to access the layout item?